# R: getting axis labels on parallel coordinates plot

Tags: r, plot

I am having difficulty trying to get labels on my parcoord() plot. If I do :

```
library(MASS)
data1<-cbind.data.frame("A"=rbind(6,9,10))
data2<-cbind.data.frame("B"=rbind(3,19,1))
parcoord(cbind(data1,data2), col=1, lty=1)
axis(2, at=c(6,9,10), labels=c("this","should","bealabel"))
```

I do not get labels the left hand side of the plot.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't the y-axis be on the scale of [1,19]?  Why did it rescale?

Comment: If you look at the code for `parcoord` (type it into the console), you'll see the first line is `rx <- apply(x, 2L, range, na.rm = TRUE)` and the second line is `x <- apply(x, 2L, function(x) (x - min(x, na.rm = TRUE))/(max(x, na.rm = TRUE) - min(x, na.rm = TRUE)))`.  `x` is what's being plotted on the y-axis.  So the rescaling is simply what `parcoord` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `y-axis` has been rescaled to `[0,1]`. Simply try `axis(2)` to see what the default axis is. Therefore, when you do `at = c(6, 9, 10)`, that is beyond the range hence not displayed. Here is a solution:

```
y <- c(6, 9, 10)
pos <- (y - min(y)) / diff(range(y))  ## rescaling
parcoord(cbind(data1,data2), col=1, lty=1)
axis(2, at=pos, labels=c("this","should","bealabel"))
```

[image]